# Summarize data with condition and create new row (dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr

I'll try illustrate my question with an example.

Sample data frame:

```
myData <- data.frame(Country = c("Germany","UK","Mexico","Spain"),
                     MyCount = c(300,800,950,125),
                     Continent = c("Europe","Europe","America","Europe"))  

Country  MyCount Continent
Germany  300     Europe
UK       800     Europe
Mexico   950     America
Spain    125     Europe
```

Expected result:

```
Country MyCount Continent
Other   425     Europe
UK      800     Europe
```

I have tried this.

```
myData %>%
  filter(Continent == "Europe" & MyCount < 800)%>%
  add_row(Country = "Other", MyCount = sum(MyCount), Continent = "Europe")
```

Comment: Please make it more clear what you'd like to do and what you are struggling with?  Are you simply trying to add a row to the data.frame?  Are you trying to summarize the data in some particular fashion?

Comment: @jmuhlenkamp  yes I need create new row from sum myCount but only where is myCount<800 and where Continent is Europe and then delete old  rows for this it is Germany and Spain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mandy I'm not entrily clear on the specific requirmnts for your use case but this should work based on your comments. Uses `group_by` and `summarise` from dplyr.

```
myData %>% 
       filter(Continent == 'Europe') %>% 
       mutate(grp = ifelse(MyCount < 800, 'Other', Country)) %>% 
       group_by(grp) %>% 
       summarise(MyCount = sum(MyCount))

# A tibble: 2 × 2
grp MyCount
<chr>   <dbl>
1 Other     425
2    UK     800
```

Comment: I'd add `as.character(Country)` to the ifelse statement, because when I try your code it shows '4' instead of UK in the output, as if it has turned into factor.

Comment: Yea I figured that was becasue of how OP setup the data.frame for the toy problem. If not, this would be better to avoid factors at all `myData <- data.frame(Country = c("Germany","UK","Mexico","Spain"),
                     MyCount = c(300,800,950,125),
                     Continent = c("Europe","Europe","America","Europe")), stringsAsFactors = FALSE`

Answer (score 1):

If I am analyzing your sample right, the following would be one way to go. You seem to want data from Europe, then aggregate it for countries which have more than or equal to 800 in MyCount and other European countries. If so, you could replace all levels of European countries with "Other" for those which have less than 800 in MyCount and aggregate the data.

```
filter(myData, Continent == "Europe") %>%
group_by(Country = fct_other(Country, keep = Country[MyCount >= 800])) %>%
summarise(MyCount = sum(MyCount))

#  Country MyCount
#   <fctr>   <dbl>
#1      UK     800
#2   Other     425
```

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely clear what you are looking for, but this will give you the result you have posted in the question.

```
library(dplyr)
myData<-data.frame(Country=c("Germany","UK","Mexico","Spain"),MyCount=c(300,800,950,125),Continent=c("Europe","Europe","America","Europe")) 

myData %>%
    filter(Continent == 'Europe') %>%
    mutate(Country = as.character(Country),
           Country = ifelse(Country %in% c('UK'), Country, 'Other')) %>%
    group_by(Country, Continent) %>%
    summarize(MyCount = sum(MyCount)) %>%
    select(Country, MyCount, Continent)

# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   Country [2]
   Country MyCount Continent
     <chr>   <dbl>    <fctr>
1   Other     425    Europe
2      UK     800    Europe
```